# Prefix sums weighted by a polynomial expression, can you do faster?

Tags: algorithm

I have been given the following exercise:

Given polynomial *P* and a real sequence *x<sub>1</sub>*, ..., *x<sub>n</sub>*, find data structure *D* that can evaluate expressions of the form *S(i, j) = P(0)x<sub>i</sub> + P(1)x<sub>i + 1</sub> + ... + P(j - i - 1)x<sub>j - 1</sub>* in constant time with some preprocessing done on *x<sub>1</sub>*, ..., *x<sub>n</sub>*.

I have been trying to solve it for quite some time now and have not had much of a success. An obvious solution requires *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* preprocessing time: for every *j* in *1 ... n*, I can calculate *P(j) = a<sub>0</sub> + ja<sub>1</sub> + j<sup>2</sup>a<sub>2</sub> + ...+ j<sup>m</sup>a<sub>m</sub>* in *O(mn)* time. Then I can calculate prefix sums for any *S(i, j)* where *j > i* in *O(n)* time for each distinct *i*, thus proceeding in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time altogether. (I am just taking regular prefix sums separately for every possible *i*.) I would like to go (asymptotically) faster than this, if possible.

The problem seems to be that the calculation of *S(i, j)* yields no useful information about *S(i + 1, j)*. Look: *S(i, j) = P(0)x<sub>1</sub> + P(1)x<sub>2</sub> + ...*, but *S(i + 1, j) = P(0)x<sub>2</sub> + P(1)x<sub>3</sub>*. See? The *P*'s have moved right. If there was a way to calculate *S(i + 1, j)* from *S(i, j)*, I believe I could proceed in *O(mn)* time.

I have tried:

- Calculate (regular) prefix sums for *x<sub>1</sub>*, ..., *x<sub>n</sub>* and manipulating the expressions so that the regular prefix sum could be used  to calculate *S(i, j)* with no success.
- Write the explicit formula for *S(i, j)* and grouping the terms by polynomial coefficients (*a<sub>i</sub>*'s) rather than by  *x<sub>i</sub>*'s. The problem remains the same.

If you can do faster, please, give me a hint how to proceed. **Please do not give explicit solutions**, I would like to figure it out myself.

P.S.: There is a hint given, actually, to solve this: "Generalize prefix sums."

Comment: It might be worthwhile asking if P was intended to be bounded-degree.

Comment: Maybe start with a data structure for _i > m_, and continue with _i=m, i=m-1_ ...

Comment: @greybeard, by *m* do you actually mean the degree of the polynomial or do you suppose I proceed backwards?

Comment: @David Both: with _m_ I mean the degree of the polynomial (of maximum degree, if need be), **and** I suggest to proceed backwards.

Comment: @greybeard, I can't see where this gets me.

Comment: @David - Sorry, I mixed up _i_ and _j - i (= d)_. (getting too long - suggesting _k_ for the parameter in _P(k)_.) Even with _d_ only bounded by _n_, all but _m_ coefficients are zero, so I took computing each _P(k)_ to take constant time (O(_m_), happily ignoring the size of _k_ to the _mth_ power). And I overlooked there would still be O(_n_) _P(k)_s to add up. I don't see how preprocessing the sequence helps, how to apply prefix sums, or how to generalize the latter helpfully. (And precomputation/memoization of Pj doesn't seem essential.)

Comment: I think you can get O(nm) preprocessing time and O(m) queries. Is that considered "fast"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `O(nm+m^2)` preprocessing and memory, and `O(m)` query time. If your `m` is bounded, that is basically that running time you were asking for.

Since you asked not to be given too direct hints, I will just show you how you might solve your task, if you were using the simple polynomial `P(x) = x`.

Define (and precalculate in time `O(nm)`:

```
Q0(j) = Sum_{0<=k<j} x_k
Q1(j) = Sum_{0<=k<j} k*x_k
```

We then have:

```
S(i,j) = Sum_{i<=k<j} (k-i)*x_k
       = Sum_{i<=k<j} k*x_k - i*Sum_{i<=k<j} x_k
       = Q1(j)-Q1(i) - i*(Q0(j)-Q0(i))
```

For constant time queries.

With a bit of sum manipulation, the generalization of the above takes `O(m^2)` time per query for general polynomials. However with an additional `O(nm+m^2)` preprocessing you can get down to `O(m)` query time. I conjecture this is optimal for memory usage linear in `n`.